# how to delete the remaining last word within a string in a textbox1

Tags: c#

how can I delete the last remaining word within a string in a textbox like this;

Values in textbox1: "this is my first time of learning c#"

I have been able to delete each word from the left until the last remaining word which is "C#" using this code;

```
string word = textbox1.Text;
if (word.Length > 0)
{
    int k = word.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
    string ster = word.Substring(k);
    textbox1.Text = ster;
}
```

After repeatedly executing this code, the below table shows the result displayed in the textbox:

| Iteration | Result |
| --- | --- |
|  | this is my first time of learning c# |
| 1 | is my first time of learning c# |
| 2 | my first time of learning c# |
| 3 | first time of learning c# |
| 4 | time of learning c# |
| 5 | of learning c# |
| 6 | learning c# |
| 7 | c# |
| 8 | c# |
| 9 | c# |

But I don't know how to delete the remaining word `"C#"` from the textbox1.

Comment: if `k == 0` then set `textbox1.Text` to `string.Empty`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that at the end there is no space to build the *next* substring index from, one approach is to inject a space, so that the value of `k` will still be non-zero for the final word, or resort to branching logic:

```
string word = textbox1.Text + " "; // Hack: create the final space 
if (word.Length > 1) // adjust for our Hack
{
    int k = word.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
    string ster = word.Substring(k);
    textbox1.Text = ster;
}
```

Branching version:

```
string word = textbox1.Text;
if (word.Length > 0)
{
    int k = word.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
    if (k > 0)
    {
        string ster = word.Substring(k);
        textbox1.Text = ster;
    }
    else
        textbox1.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

> Neither of these solutions is any more *valid* than the other, however I find the branching logic (in this case) is easier to interpret the thought process, whereas injecting a space really needs some documentation for your peers who are reviewing the code or coming back in the future to maintain it to understand the intent and your original thought process.

It is possible to further in-line both of these solutions, (reduce the lines of code to express the same logic) however if you are just starting out, there is no penalty to using up additional lines of code and characters to make your code more readable and expressive.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

```
var phrase =  "this is my first time of learning c#";
var withoutLastWord = phrase.Remove(phrase.LastIndexOf(' '));
    
Console.WriteLine($"'{withoutLastWord}'");

// Output: 'this is my first time of learning'
```

Comment: It's not very clear but I suspect that OP was manually executing the code to remove one word at a time, so in effect this answer would suffer from the same problem once the sentence is reduced to a single word (no spaces to match on)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that this is a feature that removes each word when each time executes.

```
string word = textbox1.Text;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
{
    return;
}
    
List<string> wordList = word.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
wordList.RemoveAt(0);

textbox1.Text = String.Join(" ", wordList);
```

For the explanation, I split the `word` variable by whitespace into `List<string>` and remove the first word in the sentence.

> Added Trim() to avoid code break when the `word` variable contains space at beginning or end.

> Validate the string `IsNullOrEmpty`, if true, then the statements after `if` condition will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

simply add a " " at the end of your string, the issue that you are facing is because that there is no space after (c#) so it was not able  to substring it

Answer (score 0):

Let's jiggle your logic a bit. Instead of:

```
if (word.Length > 0)
```

We can ask if it contains a space, then it gets easy to know that if it doesn't, we can just set the box to empty:

```
string word = textbox1.Text;
if (word.Contains(" "))
{
    int k = word.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
    string ster = word.Substring(k);
    textbox1.Text = ster;
} else 
    textbox1.Text = "";
```

Of course, this searches for a space twice; once for a Contains and once for an indexOf. In a performance critical application (this isn't but one day it could be a consideration) we can do the search once, by moving the IndexOf:

```
string word = textbox1.Text;
int k = word.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
if (k > 0)
{
    string ster = word.Substring(k);
    textbox1.Text = ster;
}else 
    textbox1.Text = "";
```

IndexOf returns -1 for "not found" which your +1 will then turn into 0; this means by asking if `k` is greater than 0 or not we can know if we are at the last word and whether we should substring or just blank the box

Answer (score 0):

```
textbox1.Text = string.Join(' ', textbox1.Text.Split(' ').Skip(1));
```

Comment: @BDL It does remove the first word, as requested by OP (even if I agree that the question title is misleading).

Comment: You are absolutely right. And the title *is* misleading.